# Activity Monitor doesn't show all CPU usage

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, catalina, gcc

This seems to be new behavior in macOS Catalina.  While compiling a large C project with `make -j8`, the CPU is obviously pegged at 100%, but Activity Monitor doesn't show all the busy processes.  I have it set in the View menu to show *All Processes*.  I'm guessing this has something to do with Catalina's new sandboxing security features, preventing Activity Monitor from seeing what I'm doing?

[image][image]